# Install svgalib on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04

Is it possible to install svgalib over Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS? If no, I'd be glade to know why, If yes, instructions would be much appreciated.

What I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y svgalib-bin
```

Which leads me to:

```
E: Unable to locate package svgalib-bin
```

So looking for another way, I ended up downloading the `.deb` from [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/14.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/svgalib-bin_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb.html), get me to:

```
sudo apt install ./svgalib-bin_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb
```

Which leads to the following:

```
svgalib-bin : Depends: libsvga1 but it is not installable
```

Executing

```
sudo apt-get install -y libsvga1
```

Leads to

```
E: Unable to locate package libsvga1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `rmadison svgalib-bin`, this package was last available for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*trusty*):

> ```
> $ rmadison svgalib
> svgalib | 1:1.4.3-31 | precise/universe | source
> svgalib | 1:1.4.3-33 | trusty/universe  | source
> ```

If you really need this application, then download and install all necessary packages manually from 14.04 LTS repositories:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6.15_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/svgalib/libsvga1_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/svgalib/svgalib-bin_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6.15_amd64.deb ./libsvga1_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb ./svgalib-bin_1.4.3-33_amd64.deb
```